# Problem with fetching and displaying data (users) from database

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am having trouble with trying to fetch and display all registered users from the database on index.php page in php mvc project designed for learning purposes. The problem is when I'm not logged in I get error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: users in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\App\Controllers\UserController.php
```

but when I am logged in I get the same error, but then undefined variable is 'name'. I tried searching for posts that have similar errors but I haven't been able to solve this. Any help is appreciated. Here is some of my code

UserController

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Core\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($controller, $action)
    {
        parent::__construct($controller, $action);
        $this->UserModel = $this->load_model('User');
    }

    public function createUserSessionAction($user)
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user->email;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user->name;
        redirect('home/index');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
            $users = $this->UserModel->findAllUsersByName($name);
        }
        $this->view->render('users/index', $users);
    }
```

User

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Core\Database;

class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function findAllUsersByName($name)
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = :name');
        $this->db->bind(':name', $name['name']);
        $row = $this->db->resultSet();
        if ($this->db->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php 

    use App\Models\User;

    $users = new User;

    ?>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $user->id; ?> </td>                 
                    <td><?php echo $user->name; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like to be able to display names of all registered users from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score -1):

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
            $users = $this->UserModel->findAllUsersByName($name);
        }
        $this->view->render('users/index', $users);
    }
```

In line 4 you use the variable `$name` but you didn't define it anywhere. But if you don't come into this condition, the variable `$users` is never defined.

Comment: I thought that I defined $name in User class in findAllUsersByName method. How should procede and define it if it is not defined?

Comment: You have to declare it before the call; e.g. `$name = $_SESSION['user_name];`

Comment: With little tweaking with the method findAllUsersByName method I managed to get rid of the error, but it still doesn't display users on page. It's just blank page.

Comment: what do you think, will be stored in `$users` in your `index.php`?

Comment: session maybe??

Comment: no offense; but you should learn the basics before starting with a bigger project. If you know about variable scopes, data types and objects it'll be much easier to code the stuff